# Can't install Visual Studio Code extensions

Tags: visual-studio-code

I downloaded the most recent version of Visual Studio Code for Windows.

When i try to download and install an extension through the application itself, i'm getting a `Failed to install extension x` error.
When i then click on `Download Manually` and double click to install, i'm getting the following error:

> Installation failed. The installation was unable to install the
>   extension to all the selected products. For more information, click on
>   the install log link at the bottom of the dialog.

This is what appears in that log:

```
2019-11-29 9:17:27 AM - Searching for applicable products...
2019-11-29 9:17:27 AM - Found installed product - Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2015
2019-11-29 9:17:27 AM - Found installed product - Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015
2019-11-29 9:17:27 AM - Found installed product - Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Shell (Integrated)
2019-11-29 9:17:27 AM - Found installed product - Global Location
2019-11-29 9:17:27 AM - Found installed product - ssms
2019-11-29 9:17:27 AM - VSIXInstaller.NoApplicableSKUsException: This extension is not installable on any currently installed products.
   at VSIXInstaller.App.InitializeInstall(Boolean isRepairSupported)
   at VSIXInstaller.App.InitializeInstall()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
```

What is the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link that makes you change the DNS to google DNS

https://www.techworm.net/2016/08/change-default-dns-google-dns-fast-internet-speeds.html

it's very helpful and worked with me.

Here are the necessary steps for windows:

Step 1

First of all, in your windows PC go to the Control Panel and select Network and sharing center.

Step 2

And there click on Change adapter settings.

Step 3

Right click on the internet connection u have and select properties

Step 4

Choose internet Protocol Version 4 and click on properties box on the same window

Step 5

In General Tab, In the last box, Choose "Using the following DNS"

Step 6

```
Prefered DNS: 8.8.8.8
Alternative DNS: 8.8.4.4
```

Comment: Hey, please try to sum up the content of links in your answer - otherwise, a broken link will make it useless :)

Comment: Step 1. First of all, in your windows PC go to the Control Panel and select Network and sharing center.

Step 2. And there click on Change adapter settings.
step 3. right click on the internet connection u have and select properties
Step 4. Choose internet Protocol Version 4 and click on properties box on the same window
Step 5. In General Tab, In the last box, Choose "Using the following DNS"
Step 6. Prefered DNS: 8.8.8.8
Step 7. Alternative DNS: 8.8.4.4